# the division is displaying over the content

Tags: javascript, html

I am displaying a search box in a division, on that i am using hide and display script. but when i click on the show the search button is displaying on the content which is available below.
[image: advance search where i used the script]
[image: and the content is coming over the content]

```
    <div id="showmenu">Advance Search</div>
<div class="menu" style="display: none;"><ul><li><esr-layout:search advancedSearchHref="#" /></li></ul></div>
```

script is here

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#showmenu').click(function() {
             $('.menu').slideToggle("fast");
     });
 });
```

i want to slide move the below content while showing the search box.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to slide down the bottom content when showing the search box. Then you have to change the position of search box from absolute to relative.

```
.menu{
    position : relative;
}
```

try this

Comment: can we add this in jsp?? i dont think css will work in jsp.